# Reading a .json file in static folder

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm trying to read a `.json` file from within my Flask application using:

```
def renderblog():
    with open(url_for("static", filename="blogs.json")) as blog_file:
        data = json.load(blog_file)
```

However I get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/blogs.json'
```

Now I know for a fact that the directory exists within my project structure, but I have no idea why I'm getting this error. Any ideas? Is there a specific way to retrieve `.json` in Flask?

Comment: Can you share your directory skeleton with us.

Comment: `url_for()` gives you a **url path**, not a filepath.

Comment: If I use `with open("/static/blogs.json") as blog_file:` or something similar I get the same response

Comment: @MikeResoli: yes, because `/static` is not a directory on your filesystem. That's not a relative file path.

Comment: open("static/blogs.json") if you want access it directly.

Comment: @JánosFarkas: that makes the assumption that the current working directory is in the correct place; not all WSGI servers put your process there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You generated a *URL path*, not a path to the local static folder. Use the [`app.static_folder` attribute](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Flask.static_folder) instead:

```
def renderblog():
    filename = os.path.join(app.static_folder, 'blogs.json')
    with open(filename) as blog_file:
        data = json.load(blog_file)
```